# Writing to global or local memory increases kernel execution time by 10000 %

Tags: memory-management, opencl

I have the following OpenCL kernel:

```
kernel void ndft(
    global float *re, global float *im, int num_values,
    global float *spectrum_re, global float *spectrum_im,
    global float *spectrum_abs,
    global float *sin_array, global float *cos_array,
    float sqrt_num_values_reciprocal)
{
    // MATH MAGIC - DISREGARD FROM HERE -----------

    float x;
    float y;
    float sum_re = 0;
    float sum_im = 0;

    size_t thread_id = get_global_id(0);
    //size_t local_id = get_local_id(0);

    // num_values = 24 (live environment), 48 (test)
    for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++)
    {
        x = cos_array[thread_id * num_values + i] * sqrt_num_values_reciprocal;
        y = sin_array[thread_id * num_values + i] * sqrt_num_values_reciprocal;
        sum_re = sum_re + re[i] * x + im[i] * y;
        sum_im = sum_im - re[i] * y + x * im[i];
    }

    // MATH MAGIC DONE ----------------------------

    //spectrum_re[thread_id] = sum_re;
    //spectrum_im[thread_id] = sum_im;
    //spectrum_abs[thread_id] = hypot(sum_re, sum_im);
    float asdf = hypot(sum_re, sum_im); // this is just a dummy calculation
}
```

Like this, the execution time is about 15 us (work group size = 567, 14 work groups, for a total of 7938 threads).

However, of course, I somehow need to retrieve the results of the operation, which is what the last few lines are for, (commented out). As soon as I perform a single of those memory operations (and it does not matter if `spectrum_X` is `global`, as in the example, or `local`), the exeuction time of the kernel increases to ~1.4 to 1.5 ms.

I thought the increase in execution time was some kind of fixed overhead, so I would just accumulate more data, so that the relative amount of time lost due to that effect minimizes. But when I double my number of threads (i. e. twice the amount of data), the execution time also doubles (to 2.8 ~ 3.0 ms).

I found out, that even if I only uncomment *one* of the those lines, I have the same execution time as if I uncommented all three. Even if I add a `if (thread_id == 0)` and run it, I have the same execution time. However, it is just way too slow this way (the upper limit for my application is about 30 us). It even perfoms about 5 times faster when I run it in ordinary C code on my CPU.

Now I am obviously doing something wrong but I am not sure where to start looking for a solution.

---

As I commented on talonmies' answer, I also did the following:

From the above code, I made the last 4 lines look like

```
//spectrum_re[thread_id] = sum_re;
//spectrum_im[thread_id] = sum_im;
spectrum_abs[thread_id] = hypot(sum_re, sum_im);
//float asdf = hypot(sum_re, sum_im);
```

As expected, execution time ~1.8 ms.
The generated assembler code for my system is:

```
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler
// Compiler built on Tue Apr 03 12:42:39 2012 (1333449759)
// Driver 
//

.version 3.0
.target sm_21, texmode_independent
.address_size 32


.entry ndft(
    .param .u32 .ptr .global .align 4 ndft_param_0,
    .param .u32 .ptr .global .align 4 ndft_param_1,
    .param .u32 ndft_param_2,
    .param .u32 .ptr .global .align 4 ndft_param_3,
    .param .u32 .ptr .global .align 4 ndft_param_4,
    .param .u32 .ptr .global .align 4 ndft_param_5,
    .param .u32 .ptr .global .align 4 ndft_param_6,
    .param .u32 .ptr .global .align 4 ndft_param_7,
    .param .f32 ndft_param_8
)
{
    .reg .f32   %f;
    .reg .pred  %p;
    .reg .s32   %r;


    ld.param.u32    %r3, [ndft_param_2];
    // inline asm
    mov.u32     %r18, %envreg3;
    // inline asm
    // inline asm
    mov.u32     %r19, %ntid.x;
    // inline asm
    // inline asm
    mov.u32     %r20, %ctaid.x;
    // inline asm
    // inline asm
    mov.u32     %r21, %tid.x;
    // inline asm
    add.s32     %r22, %r21, %r18;
    mad.lo.s32  %r11, %r20, %r19, %r22;
    setp.gt.s32     %p1, %r3, 0;
    @%p1 bra    BB0_2;

    mov.f32     %f46, 0f00000000;
    mov.f32     %f45, %f46;
    bra.uni     BB0_4;

BB0_2:
    ld.param.u32    %r38, [ndft_param_2];
    mul.lo.s32  %r27, %r38, %r11;
    shl.b32     %r28, %r27, 2;
    ld.param.u32    %r40, [ndft_param_6];
    add.s32     %r12, %r40, %r28;
    ld.param.u32    %r41, [ndft_param_7];
    add.s32     %r13, %r41, %r28;
    mov.f32     %f46, 0f00000000;
    mov.f32     %f45, %f46;
    mov.u32     %r43, 0;
    mov.u32     %r42, %r43;

BB0_3:
    add.s32     %r29, %r13, %r42;
    ld.global.f32   %f18, [%r29];
    ld.param.f32    %f44, [ndft_param_8];
    mul.f32     %f19, %f18, %f44;
    add.s32     %r30, %r12, %r42;
    ld.global.f32   %f20, [%r30];
    mul.f32     %f21, %f20, %f44;
    ld.param.u32    %r35, [ndft_param_0];
    add.s32     %r31, %r35, %r42;
    ld.global.f32   %f22, [%r31];
    fma.rn.f32  %f23, %f22, %f19, %f46;
    ld.param.u32    %r36, [ndft_param_1];
    add.s32     %r32, %r36, %r42;
    ld.global.f32   %f24, [%r32];
    fma.rn.f32  %f46, %f24, %f21, %f23;
    neg.f32     %f25, %f22;
    fma.rn.f32  %f26, %f25, %f21, %f45;
    fma.rn.f32  %f45, %f24, %f19, %f26;
    add.s32     %r42, %r42, 4;
    add.s32     %r43, %r43, 1;
    ld.param.u32    %r37, [ndft_param_2];
    setp.lt.s32     %p2, %r43, %r37;
    @%p2 bra    BB0_3;

BB0_4:
    // inline asm
    abs.f32     %f27, %f46;
    // inline asm
    // inline asm
    abs.f32     %f29, %f45;
    // inline asm
    setp.gt.f32     %p3, %f27, %f29;
    selp.f32    %f8, %f29, %f27, %p3;
    selp.f32    %f32, %f27, %f29, %p3;
    // inline asm
    abs.f32     %f31, %f32;
    // inline asm
    setp.gt.f32     %p4, %f31, 0f7E800000;
    mov.f32     %f47, %f32;
    @%p4 bra    BB0_6;

    mov.f32     %f48, %f8;
    bra.uni     BB0_7;

BB0_6:
    mov.f32     %f33, 0f3E800000;
    mul.rn.f32  %f10, %f8, %f33;
    mul.rn.f32  %f47, %f32, %f33;
    mov.f32     %f48, %f10;

BB0_7:
    mov.f32     %f13, %f48;
    // inline asm
    div.approx.f32  %f34, %f13, %f47;
    // inline asm
    mul.rn.f32  %f39, %f34, %f34;
    add.f32     %f38, %f39, 0f3F800000;
    // inline asm
    sqrt.approx.f32     %f37, %f38;      // <-- this is part of hypot()
    // inline asm
    mul.rn.f32  %f40, %f32, %f37;
    add.f32     %f41, %f32, %f8;
    setp.eq.f32     %p5, %f32, 0f00000000;
    selp.f32    %f42, %f41, %f40, %p5;
    setp.eq.f32     %p6, %f32, 0f7F800000;
    setp.eq.f32     %p7, %f8, 0f7F800000;
    or.pred     %p8, %p6, %p7;
    selp.f32    %f43, 0f7F800000, %f42, %p8;
    shl.b32     %r33, %r11, 2;
    ld.param.u32    %r39, [ndft_param_5];
    add.s32     %r34, %r39, %r33;
    st.global.f32   [%r34], %f43;    // <-- stores the hypot's result in spectrum_abs
    ret;
}
```

Indeed all my calculation operations are there - lots of adds/mults as well as a `sqrt` for the `hypot` function. From the above asm code, I removed the second last line:

`st.global.f32  [%r34], %f43;`

which is the line that actually stores the data in the global array `spectrum_abs`. Then I used `clCreateProgramWithBinary` and used the modified asm code file as input. Execution time went down to 20 us.

Comment: What hardware and OpenCL flavour are you running this on?

Comment: @talonmies NVIDIA GeForce 555M GT, most recent CUDA toolkit.

Comment: Are you accumulating all of the values later on? Is there a particular reason why each work item needs to compute 24 or 48 consecutive values? How did you compute sin_array and cos_array before passing them into your kernel?

Comment: @mfa The output values of this particular kernel are `spectrum_???`, and undergo further processing after this kernel (realtime application). `sin_array` and `cos_array` are precalculated in a relatively complex manner (it's not just a lookup table - it already takes a way a huge bunch of complexity by having those arrays). The for loop is there because that is just how the algorithm works - each element of the spectrum (8000 values here, can vary up to 40000 in applications) is a sum itself (of 24 respectively 48 values).

Comment: @mfa I forgot to add, the algorithm in this kernel is to be called several thousand times per second.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would guess you are seeing the effects of compiler optimization.

The NVIDIA compiler is very aggressive at eliminating "dead code" which does not directly participate in a write to global memory. So in your kernel, if you don't write `sum_re` or `sum_im`, the compiler will optimize the whole computation loop (and probably everything else) and leave your with an empty kernel containing nothing more than a no-op. The 15 microsecond execution time you are seeing is mostly just kernel launch overhead and not much else. When you uncomment a global memory write, then the compiler leaves all the computation code in place, and you see the true execution time of your code.

So the real question you should probably be asking is how to optimize that kernel to reduce its execution time from the 1.5 milliseconds it currently takes towards your (very ambitous) 30 microsecond target.

---

Despite the skepticism expressed to the original answer, here is a complete repro case which supports the assertion that this is a compiler related effect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>

size_t source_size;
const char * source_str =
"kernel void ndft(                                                                     \n" \
"    global float *re, global float *im, int num_values,                               \n" \
"    global float *spectrum_re, global float *spectrum_im,                             \n" \
"    global float *spectrum_abs,                                                       \n" \
"    global float *sin_array, global float *cos_array,                                 \n" \
"    float sqrt_num_values_reciprocal)                                                 \n" \
"{                                                                                     \n" \
"    // MATH MAGIC - DISREGARD FROM HERE -----------                                   \n" \
"                                                                                      \n" \
"    float x;                                                                          \n" \
"    float y;                                                                          \n" \
"    float sum_re = 0;                                                                 \n" \
"    float sum_im = 0;                                                                 \n" \
"                                                                                      \n" \
"    size_t thread_id = get_global_id(0);                                              \n" \
"                                                                                      \n" \
"    for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++)                                              \n" \
"    {                                                                                 \n" \
"        x = cos_array[thread_id * num_values + i] * sqrt_num_values_reciprocal;       \n" \
"        y = sin_array[thread_id * num_values + i] * sqrt_num_values_reciprocal;       \n" \
"        sum_re += re[i] * x + im[i] * y;                                              \n" \
"        sum_im -= re[i] * y + x * im[i];                                              \n" \
"    }                                                                                 \n" \
"                                                                                      \n" \
"    // MATH MAGIC DONE ----------------------------                                   \n" \
"                                                                                      \n" \
"    //spectrum_re[thread_id] = sum_re;                                                \n" \
"    //spectrum_im[thread_id] = sum_im;                                                \n" \
"    //spectrum_abs[thread_id] = hypot(sum_re, sum_im);                                \n" \
"}                                                                                     \n";

int main(void)
{
    int err;

    cl_device_id device_id;  
    clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &err);

    err = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    cl_uint program_num_devices;
    clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_NUM_DEVICES, sizeof(cl_uint), &program_num_devices, NULL);

    size_t * binaries_sizes = new size_t[program_num_devices];
    clGetProgramInfo( program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, program_num_devices*sizeof(size_t), binaries_sizes, NULL);

    char **binaries = new char*[program_num_devices];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < program_num_devices; i++)
        binaries[i] = new char[binaries_sizes[i]+1];

    clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES, program_num_devices*sizeof(size_t), binaries, NULL);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < program_num_devices; i++)
    {
        binaries[i][binaries_sizes[i]] = '\0';
        std::cout << "Program " << i << ":" << std::endl;
        std::cout << binaries[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and run, it emits the follow PTX code from the OpenCL runtime:

```
Program 0:
bplist00?^clBinaryDriver\clBinaryData_clBinaryVersionWCLH 1.0O!.version 1.5
.target sm_12
.target texmode_independent

.reg .b32  r<126>; /* define r0..125 */ 
.reg .b64  x<126>; /* define r0..125 */ 
.reg .b32  f<128>; /* define f0..127 */ 
.reg .pred p<32>; /* define p0..31 */ 
.reg .u32  sp;

.reg .b8   wb0,wb1,wb2,wb3; /* 8-bit write buffer */ 
.reg .b16  ws0,ws1,ws2,ws3; /* 16-bit write buffer */ 
.reg .b32  tb0,tb1,tb2,tb3; /* read tex buffer */ 
.reg .b64  vl0,vl1; /* 64-bit vector buffer */ 
.reg .b16  cvt16_0,cvt16_1; /* tmps for conversions */ 


.const .align 1 .b8 ndft_gid_base[52];
.local .align 16 .b8 ndft_stack[8];
.entry ndft(
    .param.b32 ndft_0  /* re */,
    .param.b32 ndft_1  /* im */,
    .param.b32 ndft_2  /* num_values */,
    .param.b32 ndft_3  /* spectrum_re */,
    .param.b32 ndft_4  /* spectrum_im */,
    .param.b32 ndft_5  /* spectrum_abs */,
    .param.b32 ndft_6  /* sin_array */,
    .param.b32 ndft_7  /* cos_array */,
    .param.f32 ndft_8  /* sqrt_num_values_reciprocal */
) {
    mov.u32 sp, ndft_stack;
    mov.u32 r0, 4294967295;
    ld.param.u32 r1, [ndft_2 + 0];
LBB1_1:
    add.u32 r0, r0, 1;
    setp.lt.s32 p0, r0, r1;
    @p0 bra LBB1_1;
LBB1_2:
    ret;
}
```

ie. a kernel stub containing none of the computation loop. When the three global memory writes in the last three lines of the kernel are uncommented, it emits this:

```
Program 0:
S.version 1.5inaryDriver\clBinaryData_clBinaryVersionWCLH 1.0O
.target sm_12
.target texmode_independent

.reg .b32  r<126>; /* define r0..125 */ 
.reg .b64  x<126>; /* define r0..125 */ 
.reg .b32  f<128>; /* define f0..127 */ 
.reg .pred p<32>; /* define p0..31 */ 
.reg .u32  sp;

.reg .b8   wb0,wb1,wb2,wb3; /* 8-bit write buffer */ 
.reg .b16  ws0,ws1,ws2,ws3; /* 16-bit write buffer */ 
.reg .b32  tb0,tb1,tb2,tb3; /* read tex buffer */ 
.reg .b64  vl0,vl1; /* 64-bit vector buffer */ 
.reg .b16  cvt16_0,cvt16_1; /* tmps for conversions */ 


.const .align 1 .b8 ndft_gid_base[52];
.local .align 16 .b8 ndft_stack[8];
.entry ndft(
    .param.b32 ndft_0  /* re */,
    .param.b32 ndft_1  /* im */,
    .param.b32 ndft_2  /* num_values */,
    .param.b32 ndft_3  /* spectrum_re */,
    .param.b32 ndft_4  /* spectrum_im */,
    .param.b32 ndft_5  /* spectrum_abs */,
    .param.b32 ndft_6  /* sin_array */,
    .param.b32 ndft_7  /* cos_array */,
    .param.f32 ndft_8  /* sqrt_num_values_reciprocal */
) {
    mov.u32 sp, ndft_stack;
    cvt.u32.u16 r0, %tid.x;
    cvt.u32.u16 r1, %ntid.x;
    cvt.u32.u16 r2, %ctaid.x;
    mad24.lo.u32 r0, r2, r1, r0;
    mov.u32 r1, 0;
    shl.b32 r2, r1, 2;
    mov.u32 r3, ndft_gid_base;
    add.u32 r2, r2, r3;
    ld.const.u32 r2, [r2 + 40];
    add.u32 r0, r0, r2;
    ld.param.u32 r2, [ndft_2 + 0];
    mul.lo.u32 r3, r0, r2;
    shl.b32 r3, r3, 2;
    mov.f32 f0, 0f00000000 /* 0.000000e+00 */;
    ld.param.f32 f1, [ndft_8 + 0];
    ld.param.u32 r4, [ndft_7 + 0];
    ld.param.u32 r5, [ndft_6 + 0];
    ld.param.u32 r6, [ndft_5 + 0];
    ld.param.u32 r7, [ndft_4 + 0];
    ld.param.u32 r8, [ndft_3 + 0];
    ld.param.u32 r9, [ndft_1 + 0];
    ld.param.u32 r10, [ndft_0 + 0];
    mov.u32 r11, r1;
    mov.f32 f2, f0;
LBB1_1:
    setp.ge.s32 p0, r11, r2;
    @!p0 bra    LBB1_7;
LBB1_2:
    shl.b32 r1, r0, 2;
    add.u32 r2, r8, r1;
    st.global.f32 [r2+0], f0;
    add.u32 r1, r7, r1;
    st.global.f32 [r1+0], f2;
    abs.f32 f1, f2;
    abs.f32 f0, f0;
    setp.gt.f32 p0, f0, f1;
    selp.f32 f2, f0, f1, p0;
    abs.f32 f3, f2;
    mov.f32 f4, 0f7E800000 /* 8.507059e+37 */;
    setp.gt.f32 p1, f3, f4;
    selp.f32 f0, f1, f0, p0;
    shl.b32 r0, r0, 2;
    add.u32 r0, r6, r0;
    @!p1 bra    LBB1_8;
LBB1_3:
    mul.rn.f32 f3, f2, 0f3E800000 /* 2.500000e-01 */;
    mul.rn.f32 f1, f0, 0f3E800000 /* 2.500000e-01 */;
LBB1_4:
    mov.f32 f4, 0f00000000 /* 0.000000e+00 */;
    setp.eq.f32 p0, f2, f4;
    @!p0 bra    LBB1_9;
LBB1_5:
    add.f32 f1, f2, f0;
LBB1_6:
    mov.f32 f3, 0f7F800000 /* inf */;
    setp.eq.f32 p0, f0, f3;
    setp.eq.f32 p1, f2, f3;
    or.pred p0, p1, p0;
    selp.f32 f0, f3, f1, p0;
    st.global.f32 [r0+0], f0;
    ret;
LBB1_7:
    add.u32 r12, r3, r1;
    add.u32 r13, r4, r12;
    ld.global.f32 f3, [r13+0];
    mul.rn.f32 f3, f3, f1;
    add.u32 r13, r9, r1;
    ld.global.f32 f4, [r13+0];
    mul.rn.f32 f5, f3, f4;
    add.u32 r12, r5, r12;
    ld.global.f32 f6, [r12+0];
    mul.rn.f32 f6, f6, f1;
    add.u32 r12, r10, r1;
    ld.global.f32 f7, [r12+0];
    mul.rn.f32 f8, f7, f6;
    add.f32 f5, f8, f5;
    sub.f32 f2, f2, f5;
    mul.rn.f32 f4, f4, f6;
    mul.rn.f32 f3, f7, f3;
    add.f32 f3, f3, f4;
    add.f32 f0, f0, f3;
    add.u32 r11, r11, 1;
    add.u32 r1, r1, 4;
    bra LBB1_1;
LBB1_8:
    mov.f32 f1, f0;
    mov.f32 f3, f2;
    bra LBB1_4;
LBB1_9:
    div.approx.f32 f1, f1, f3;
    mul.rn.f32 f1, f1, f1;
    add.f32 f1, f1, 0f3F800000 /* 1.000000e+00 */;
    sqrt.approx.ftz.f32 f1, f1;
    mul.rn.f32 f1, f2, f1;
    bra LBB1_6;
}
```

I think this is pretty irrefutable evidence that it is compiler optimisation which is causes the difference in runtime, and depends only on whether memory writes are included in the kernel code or not.

---

I guess the final question then becomes why this is so slow (irrespective of the debate about whether this is caused by compiler optimization or not). The 1.5 millisecond runtime you are seeing is a true reflection of the performance of the code and the real question is why. From my reading of your kernel code, the answer looks to lie in memory access patterns which are pretty horrible for the GPU. Inside the compute loop you have a two global memory reads with very large strides, like this one:

```
x = cos_array[thread_id * num_values + i] * sqrt_num_values_reciprocal;
```

According to the comment in your code `num_values` is either 24 or 48. That means the memory reads can't possibly coalesce, and the L1 cache on a Fermi GPU isn't going to be much help either. This will have a huge negative impact on memory bandwidth utilisation and make the code very slow. If you are stuck with that input data ordering, then a faster solution would be to use a warp to do the computation of a one output (so do a warp wide reduction to the final sum). This will reduce the read stride from 24 or 48 to 1 and coalesce the global memory reads from those two large input arrays.

Inside the loop there is also repeated fetches to global memory for either 24 or 48 elements of `re` and `im`:

```
    sum_re += re[i] * x + im[i] * y;
    sum_im -= re[i] * y + x * im[i];
```

This is unnecessary, and wastes a lot of global memory bandwidth or cache efficiency (the GPU doesn't have enough registers to let the compiler hold the whole of each array in register). It would be far better to have each work group read those two arrays into `__local` memory arrays once and use the local memory copy inside the compute loop. If you have each work group compute multiple times, rather than just once, then you can potentially save a lot of global memory bandwidth and amortise the initial read until it is almost free.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but this is not the case. I have verified the assembly code that the compiler generates and it definitely contains my operations.

Comment: Did you look at the PTX or the SASS? If you looked at the PTX, the optimization may have been done by the JIT PTX assembler.

Comment: @RogerDahl I'm sorry I don't know what those are. I looked at what the JIT compiler produced by querying GetProgramInfo. But nonetheless executing the same kernel *with* memory access on my CPU instead of the GPU takes only 40 to 45 us, and the results are there. Therefore I doubt that the optimization theory is correct.

Comment: CUDA C gets compiled to a virtual machine called PTX. So when you look at the output from the compiler, that is what you'll see. The PTX becomes embedded in your executable (you can see it by opening the executable in a text editor). When you run your executable, a JIT compiler in the GPU driver takes the PTX and generates SASS, which is machine code for your specific GPU.

Comment: Oops! Hm. What am I doing here? I don't subscribe to the OpenCL tag :) Anyway, probably the same principle, right?

Comment: I haven't noticed that you updated your answer (stackoverflow doesn't notify you then) and you have made me skeptical of myself. However, the asm output I get is totally different from yours (*most* of the calculations are there, but for example the `hypot` is indeed optimized away). It seems totally platform dependent. Then I did: Uncomment only the `spectrum_abs` line, look at the generated ASM, verify that the `hypot` is there, uncomment *only* the `st.global.f32` operation (not the sqrt), and the execution time went from 1.8 ms to 20 us. I will add the asm to my question.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Any decent compiler will discard unused computations, branches, etc.. 15us is also a bit suspicious -- have you timed how long a NOP function call takes? (typically 0, 15, or 16us) If you are still seeing the full assembly when you compile it, my guess is that it is being cut out at runtime or somewhere in the JIT process.

Comment: @mfa That might be the case. Do you have any idea how I could verify that? Also don't forget that running the same OpenCL kernel code on my Intel CPU is already significantly faster than on the GPU, even though it is perfectly vectorizable. Also doesn't a NOP only take one clock cycle (500 MHz - 0.002 us), or am I wrong there?

Comment: I am referring to a host-side empty function, not an empty kernel when I give the NOP example. NOP itself doesn't take much time, but traditionally the call to (and from) a function requires stack pushes/pops which aren't free. As for how to test your kernel, I suggest profiling vs an empty kernel with the same params. Then try the 'empty' kernel again with only the write operations -- maybe write a constant value to all outputs -- but no math. There's no way an empty kernel is not a lot faster than the math you're computing, unless your kernel is compiler-chopped in some way.

Comment: @dialer: The PTX assembler can do quite a lot to the code, although I am not sure about dead code removal. It might well be able to work out that certain register results never get written anywhere and just cull them out completely. I added another edit to my answer with some rough analysis of the code and optimization suggestions you might want to try.

Comment: @talonmies Okay now I must really thank both of you for your seemingly unlimited patience with me and apologize for my stubbornness. It is indeed the `cos_array[thread_id * num_values + i]` which adds about 35 us per access. Out of all the things I would have never expected that. Since the usage of those arrays was the greatest boost on the pure `C` language implementation I thoguht it would only be profitable, but not so on the GPU. I find it unfortunate though that `GetProgramInfo` doesn't give you the *real* code as it seems.