# Massive performance loss when writing data

Tags: cuda

I do some calculations in my code on a float* memory block. Since I am working on an image, I will have to do this with width * height points, and 180 rotations. I am starting 180 threads (1 per degree rotation), since this is the only parallelizable procedure in the code.
I rotate the images, and get for every rotation, for every point a resulting float value.
I have another float* block which stores the current maximum value at each point.

```
if(resultMap[i] < convrst)
{
    resultMap[i] = convrst;
    rMap[i] = (unsigned char)r0;
    oMap[i] = (unsigned char)index;
}
```

with resultMap storing the current highest value. convrst is the result of the convolution, and if the current result is higher than the ones before, it will save the value, plus the radius (r0) and rotation (index) at that point. r0 is originally an int, as well as index.
i is an counter going from 0 to imgsize-1

Without the assignments in the { } part, the whole code will finish within like 2s, with the assignments it takes like 50s (and this is not taking into account that in that code I left out the locks to avoid synchronization problems).

Why is that code so slow, and what can I do to make it finish faster?

Comment: what gpu are you running this on?

Comment: This is a laptop with a Core i5-2410M and a GeForce GT 540M

Comment: How many blocks are you running the kernel with? 180 threads is a **tiny** (and wrong) number of threads to use, even for a 2 SM GPU like your GT 540M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the large slowdown when you include writes in your kernel is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10494326/681865) (although it is about OpenCL the principle is the same). The NVIDIA compiler is extremely aggressive at optimising away "dead" code, that is code which does not contribute to a shared memory or global memory write. So I would guess that when you don't include a write to global memory, as shown in your question, the compiler is just optimising large amounts of the kernel away, greatly reducing the execution time.

So, as in the other question I linked to, the real question should be why your kernel taking 50 seconds to finish. That will require more information about the code and the execution parameters you are calling it with, but if, as you wrote, you are running only 180 threads, that is the likely culprit. The GPU needs a lot more parallelism than that to achieve anything like peak performance.

Comment: Thanks for that, it kind of was my suspicion that it ignores the computational expensive parts when I was leaving out the writes to memory (although I tried with Optimization off from the project properties). 
What I do: rotate the image around 180 degrees in 1 degree steps, and calculate a convolution on the rotated images. Since each convolution needs the complete image, I can't think of other ways to get more concurrent threads. Does it help if I do blocks instead of threads?
Currently both GPU and CPU take around 50s for that task, and the CPU version is not threaded at all...