# OpenCL performance on Lion

Tags: performance, macos, osx-lion, opencl

Maybe (or rather not maybe) I do something in a wrong way but it seems that I can't get good performance from OpenCl kernel even though it runs significantly faster on GPU than in CPU.

Let me explain.

CPU kernel running time is ~100ms.
GPU kernel running time is ~8ms.

Above was measured using the `clCreateCommandQueue` with `CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE` flag.

But, what is the problem is the time needed to call (enqueue) the kernel repeatedly.

200 kernel calls on CPU: ~19s
200 kernel calls on GPU: ~18s

Above was measured with calls to `gettimeofday` before and after the 200 loop. And just after the loop was the call to `clFinish` to wait until the 200 enqueued kernels are done.
Moreover, the time was measured only for enqueueing and executing the kernel, no data transfer from/to the kernel was involved.

Here is the loop:

```
size_t global_item_size = LIST_SIZE;
Start_Clock(&startTime);
for(int k=0; k<200; k++)
{
    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_item_size, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);        
}   
clFinish(command_queue);    
printf("] (in %0.4fs)\n", Stop_Clock(&startTime));
```

If 200 calls to the kernel take ~18s then it's completely irrelevant that the kernel on GPU is several times faster than on CPU...

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT

I made some additional tests and it seems that actually assigning the result of the computation to the output buffer is producing the overhead.

This kernel

```
__kernel void test_kernel(__global const float *A, __global const float *B, __global float *C) 
{
    // Get the index of the current element to be processed
    int i = get_global_id(0);

    // Do the work
    C[i] = sqrt(sin(A[i]) + tan(B[i]));
}
```

executed 200 times has the timings as above. But if I change the `C[i]` line to
`float z = sqrt(sin(A[i]) + tan(B[i]));`
then this kernel takes 0.3s on CPU and 2.6s on GPU.

Interesting.
I wonder if it would be possible to speed up the execution by collecting the results in `__local` table and then assigning them to the output buffer `C` only in the execution of the last kernel call? (the kernel with the last global id, not the 200th enqueued kernel)

Comment: See if you can unroll the for loop inside the GPU rather than having it in CPU, you can make this for loop as kernel fn and inside the kernel fn you can call your current kernel. Posting a kernel code along with host code can help other SO members better idea on how to help

Comment: Ok, maybe it's not completely irrelevant because a task that would require 100s on the CPU will be completed in 5s on the GPU. 

But in case I want to quickly refresh some "result" with new parameters and in case where this result takes only a fraction of a second to compute on GPU the speed difference would be irrelevant because now I can only get ~11 refreshes per second - no matter CPU or GPU...

Comment: @ocluser The kernel function now is: c[i] = sqrt(sin(a[i]) + tan(b[i])); So there is nothing to unroll.

Comment: The 200 loop is a simulation of calling the kernel repeatedly if update of the solution is needed because input parameters got changed. In real case this loop will be changed to some kind of notify that the kernel needs to refresh the solution. GUI slider or something similar.

Comment: first invocation of clenque will have slight overhead depending on the buffer associated with kernel, if you place first kernel or 1st iteration outside the for loop and subsequent calls(199 times) should have less overhead.

Comment: @ocluser Tried to do what you proposed. Placed one more kernel call before the loop and measured the time for 200 additional calls... unfortunately it's same - give or take small fluctuations occurring from run to run.

Comment: I never used OpenCL before. Is this something I should expect? Em I trying to correct OpenCL's normal behaviour?

Comment: Nope, only thing i would say such a minuscule kernel operation GPU may not be good option, you can as well run this in CPU and get more performance benefits. If you have large kernel which does reduce,sobelfilter or any other manipulation then this overhead is insignificant.

Comment: @bor: When you change the kernel to remove the store, the compiler is free to optimize the whole kernel away. Your measured time of 0.2s is basically the API and graphics subsystem overhead and nothing else. The kernel will take no time at all. You can further lower this overhead by not using `CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing to global or local memory increases kernel execution time by 10000 %](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494326/writing-to-global-or-local-memory-increases-kernel-execution-time-by-10000)

Comment: You should change to the `float4` data type and use 1/4 as many work items.  Your CPU context code should run tremendously faster, and if your GPU is an AMD GPU, then it will also run a lot faster.

Comment: Why do you use same event for all kernel enqueues?